# Acceso a memoria SDCard Android

Tags: java, android, filesystem

Mi objetivo es poder tener un respaldo de información que genera mi app en una memoria extraible en Android y que persista incluso si elimino el app o elimino los datos del app desde el administrador de aplicaciones.

Tengo el siguiente problema, intento crear un directorio en la SDCard extraible en Android. 
La documentación dice que usando Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() esto me retorna el directorio externo. Pero esto lo que devuelve es la dirección: **"storage/emulated/0/"**  <-- esa dirección corresponde a una partición de la memoria interna, es decir que no es lo que necesito.

Link documentación
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html?hl=es-419#filesInternal

He intentado otros métodos como *Activity.getApplicationContext().getExternalMediaDirs()*, este retorna un array con 2 direcciones, la primera es de la memoria interna y la segunda corresponde efectivamente en memoria externa, el problema es que al escribir en el fichero Media al desinstalar el app la información que dejé ahí se borra, también si por ejemplo desde el administrador de aplicaciones borras los datos, esto se debe a que el la información con este método esta ligada al app y es justo lo que no quiero.

Comment: Bienvenido Gustavo, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado!, saludos!

Comment: Hola gustavo, sigue el consejo de jorge y no seria mas optimo respaldar en la nube como google drive mismo o en una base de datos como firebase. y evitas el problema de desintalacion de tu app, etc

Comment: Si claro es lo optimo, pero la situación particularmente me obliga a trabajar con datos offline. Por ejemplo usuarios que se adentran en lugares donde la conexión es escasa o nula. Y como medida estoy intentando que en caso de que el teléfono por ejemplo caiga al agua, o se caiga y se dañe. La idea es poder recuperar los datos desde una SDCard extraible. No sé si me explico bien